# "The Conjugate of a matrix"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am having some trouble understanding a definition/question in my linear algebra text book.

The question states " If $A$ is a square matrix, a matrix of the form $P^{-1}AP$ where $P$ is invertible is called a  'Conjugate ' of $A$.

I am having trouble understanding that, is there any examples? It then asks is $P^{-1}AP=A$ and I'm not sure what direction to take. I tried $P(P^{-1}AP=A)$ , giving $AP=PA$ and then $(AP=PA)P^{-1}$ giving $A=PAP^{-1}$. But I'm not sure if this is a correct proof/ not sure what I am showing. It also asks if some conjugate of $A$ is invertible show that $A$ is invertible, not sure where to begin on that either.

Thanks so much for any help

Comment: Taking conjugates is basically viewing everything with respect to a different basis. But do not worry about its meaning too much in order to solve these questions. In your first question, you need to show if for all $A,P$ where $P$ is invertible is $P^{-1}AP =A$? Try to think of $2 \times 2$ matrices. The next question asks: if $P^{-1}AP$ is invertible, for some invertible $P$ does this mean $A$ is invertible. You can start with this: If $P^{-1}AP$ is invertible, then there is an invertible $B$ such that $P^{-1}APB = I$ which means $APB=P$ which implies $APBP^{-1}=I$.

Comment: Is there any example?  You can choose any square matrix $A$, any invertible matrix $P$ of the same size, and compute $P^{-1}AP$.  Then you will have an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) $A$ is conjugate to itself, simply choose $P = I$ the identity matrix.

2) Suppose some conjugate of $A$ is invertible $\implies \det(P^{-1}AP) \neq 0 \implies \det(A) \neq 0$ which shows that $A$ is also invertible.